# Creating RSS for any website in PHP (Similar to Feedity or Feed43)

Tags: php, rss, feed

For my Project, I want to build a PHP Script, which can create RSS for any website, just like Feedity or Feed43..
Any help regarding where to start and how would be really appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make RSS, you just need to print the correct format. First, you need to make the header:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Example RSS</title>
        <link>http://the.link.to.this.page</link>
        <description>A description of this RSS channel.</description>
        <atom:link href="http://the.link.to.this.page" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

Now, you spit out items like:

```
<item>
    <title>A title of the item</title>
    <guid>A Unique ID</guid>
    <description>The main text for the item.</description>
</item>
```

You will obvious use PHP to customize a set of items to spit out. You close it all properly with:

```
    </channel>
</rss>
```